# For loop with If not working as expected

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I have this little piece of code I'm working with. I'm a novice so kindly pardon my ignorance.

The intended logic is:

for a value in list y, find any match in list s and print out the value in list s (not list y).
My current code prints out list y but I actually want list s.

Here is my current code:

```
y = ['a','m','j']
s = ['lumberjack', 'banana split']

for x in s:
    if any(x in alpha for alpha in y):
           print x
```

I intend to print 'lumberjack' and 'banana split' but the code as is prints 'a'
Please help :)

Thank you

Comment: perhaps just a `if y in s: print s`

Comment: Your for-loop with `any` seems overly complicated. This kind of logic is often fairly simple and straightforward in python

Comment: It's hard to guess what you need when the description is so different from the code.  You write about "lists" but there aren't any in the code.

Comment: Hello Ed. Yes you are right. I simplified it to make sure everyone is on the same page. The ultimate question is: What if I have multiple elements in a list. For example y = 'a','m','j' and s = 'lumberjack', 'banana split'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing "a" is correct, if you wanna print "lumberjack", append those characters to your alpha list (i.e. variable y)

```
y = 'albumjcker' # all characters inside "lumberjack"
s = 'lumberjack'

for x in s:
    if any(x in alpha for alpha in y):
           print x
```

should do the trick

---

Try:

```
y = ["a", "b", "c", "l"]
s = ["banana split", "lumberjack"]
for words in s:
    for char in y:
        if char in words:
            print (words)
            break
```

---

```
y = ["animal","zoo","potato"] 
s =  ["The animal farm on the left","I had potatoes for lunch"]
for words in s:
    for char in y:
        if char in words:
            print (words)
            break

The animal farm on the left
I had potatoes for lunch
```

---

**Edit**

```
y = ["animal","zoo","potato"] 
s =  ["The animal farm on the left","I had potatoes for lunch"]
s = list(set(s)) # But NOTE THAT this might change the order of your original list
for words in s:
    for char in y:
        if char in words:
            print (words)
            break
```

if order is important, then i guess you can only do

```
y = ["animal","zoo","potato"] 
s =  ["The animal farm on the left","I had potatoes for lunch"]

new = []
for x in s:
    if x not in new:
        new.append(x)
s = new

for words in s:
    for char in y:
        if char in words:
            print (words)
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop you were just printing the character that you were iterating over at the time, not the full string.

```
y = 'a'
s = 'lumberjack'

for x in s:
    if any(x in alpha for alpha in y):
       print s # Return 'lumberjack'
```

**EDIT** If you have a list of characters (as your comment suggested) then:

```
y = ['a', 'z', 'b']
s = 'lumberjack'

def check_chars(s, chars):
    for char in y:
        if char in s:
            print s
            break

for s in ['lumberjack','banana split']:
    check_chars(s,y)
```

This checks whether the string in y ('a') is a substring of s ('lumberjack'), it also breaks after you've printed so you don't possibly print multiple times.

Comment: According to the question `y` will be a list though, so some loop/list comprehension might be needed

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. What if I have multiple elements in a list. For example y = 'a','m','j' and s = 'lumberjack', 'banana split' Thank you much.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :) If you could vote up my question if you think it's been of use to you then that would be great.